# how to display data from ModelMap attribute on jjsp page?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I wants to display some details from database to view page so I tried to put results returned by query on List but it is show detils like:

If I have 10 details in database then.It is showing one detail 10 times.

view page details:

```
<c:choose>
        <c:when test="${not empty dtoBean}">
            <c:forEach items="${dtoBean}" var="upComLeave">
                <tr>
                    <td><span>${upComLeave.employee_id}</span></td>
                    <td><span>${upComLeave.no_of_leave}</span></td>
                    <td><span>${upComLeave.fromDate} - ${upComLeave.toDate}</span></td>
                    <td><span>${upComLeave.leaveType}</span></td>
                    <td><span>${upComLeave.leavePeriod}</span></td>
                    <td><span>${upComLeave.appliedLeave}</span></td>
                    <td><span>${upComLeave.leaveStatus}</span></td>
                    <c:if test="${upComLeave.leaveStatus ne 'Approved' }"> //check status if accepted, don't render Accept button
                        <td><button id="btnAccept" name="action" type="submit" value="Accept${upComLeave.emp_id}" onclick="">Approve</button></td>
                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${upComLeave.leaveStatus ne 'rejected' }">//check status if accepted, don't render Reject button
                    <td><button id="btnReject" name="action" type="submit" value="Reject${upComLeave.emp_id}">Reject</button></td>
                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${upComLeave.leaveStatus eq 'cancel' }">//check status if cancel, render cancel button
                    <td><button id="btnCancel" name="action" type="submit" value="Cancel${upComLeave.emp_id}">Cancel</button></td>
                    </c:if>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            upcomingLeavesList is empty or null..
        </c:otherwise>
      </c:choose>
```

controller class:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/upcomingLeaves", method = RequestMethod.GET)
           public String showForm(@ModelAttribute("loginForm")EmpRegistrationForm profileForm, BindingResult result , HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap model){ 


             try{           
                    HttpSession session=super.getSession(model);
                    CommonDTOBean dtoBean=(CommonDTOBean)session.getAttribute("dtoBean");
                    List upcomingLeavesList=LeaveStatusWorker.upcomingLeaves(dtoBean);
                    session.setAttribute("upcomingLeavesList", upcomingLeavesList);

model.addAttribute("dtoBean",dtoBean);

                    return GlobalConstants.UPCOMING_LEAVES;
                    }catch(Exception e){

                    }


             return "redirect: GlobalConstants.UPCOMING_LEAVES";    
           }
```

DTO service class has following method to fetch details from db:

```
public static  List<CommonDTOBean> upcomingLeaves(CommonDTOBean dtoBean1) throws SQLException{
    con=DBConnection.getConnection();
    query= "select e.emp_id,e.LeaveType,e.leavePeriod,e.fromdate,e.todate,e.leave_status ,er.no_of_leave,e.no_of_leaves from EMPLEAVE e,newemp_register er where e.emp_id=er.emp_id " ;
    PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement(query);
    System.out.println( GlobalConstants.LEAVE_STATUS);
     rs=pstmt.executeQuery();

     List<CommonDTOBean> list=new ArrayList<CommonDTOBean>();

    while(rs.next()){


        dtoBean1.setEmployee_id(rs.getInt(1));
        dtoBean1.setLeaveType(rs.getString(2));
        dtoBean1.setLeavePeriod(rs.getString(3));
        dtoBean1.setFromDate(rs.getString(4));
        dtoBean1.setToDate(rs.getString(5));
        dtoBean1.setLeaveStatus(rs.getString(6));
        dtoBean1.setNo_of_leave(rs.getString(7));
        dtoBean1.setAppliedLeave(rs.getString(8));

        list.add(dtoBean1);

    }

    return list;
    }
```

And the form bean class has:

```
public class CommonDTOBean {
private int employee_id;
    private String empName;
    private String email;
    private String designation;
    private String password;
    private String DOJ;
    private String empType;
    private String leaveStatus;
    ..
    ..
    ..
// all setters and getters
}
```

Is all correct or I did something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are passing an object and updating the same for each record and adding to list. That is why it is showing same result. Instead do it like this

```
public static  List<CommonDTOBean> upcomingLeaves() throws SQLException{
    con=DBConnection.getConnection();
    query= "select e.emp_id,e.LeaveType,e.leavePeriod,e.fromdate,e.todate,e.leave_status ,er.no_of_leave,e.no_of_leaves from EMPLEAVE e,newemp_register er where e.emp_id=er.emp_id " ;
    PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement(query);
    System.out.println( GlobalConstants.LEAVE_STATUS);
     rs=pstmt.executeQuery();

     List<CommonDTOBean> list=new ArrayList<CommonDTOBean>();

    while(rs.next()){

        CommonDTOBean dtoBean1 = new CommonDTOBean ();  
        dtoBean1.setEmployee_id(rs.getInt(1));
        dtoBean1.setLeaveType(rs.getString(2));
        dtoBean1.setLeavePeriod(rs.getString(3));
        dtoBean1.setFromDate(rs.getString(4));
        dtoBean1.setToDate(rs.getString(5));
        dtoBean1.setLeaveStatus(rs.getString(6));
        dtoBean1.setNo_of_leave(rs.getString(7));
        dtoBean1.setAppliedLeave(rs.getString(8));

        list.add(dtoBean1);

    }

    return list;
    }
```

You should have new `CommonDTOBean` object for each record fetched.

Comment: Is it better to use HashMap instead of List?

Comment: Is there any way to prevent to create new object every time?Because it will consume addition memory for each object right?

Comment: You know the concept "Passing By Reference"! If you use HashMap instead of List it still fails as you are setting values to same object. No, you cannot avoid creating new Object for each record. And you no need to worry about memory consumption in these days unless you get OutOfMemoryException.